# Error when deploying app gateway via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I don't understand why I'm getting this error?

```
Error: Error Creating/Updating Application Gateway "apgw-ngd-mig-01" (Resource Group "rg-ngd-mig-inf-01"): network.ApplicationGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidResourceReference" Message="Resource /subscriptions/5397f7a7-fbed-4dd5-bf06-151e8ca58ba7/resourceGroups/rg-ngd-mig-inf-01/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/apgw-ngd-mig-01/urlPathMaps/value referenced by resource /subscriptions/5397f7a7-fbed-4dd5-bf06-151e8ca58ba7/resourceGroups/rg-ngd-mig-inf-01/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/apgw-ngd-mig-01/requestRoutingRules/default-Rule was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource 
exists, and that both resources are in the same region." Details=[]

  on appgw\main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "apgw":
   1: resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "apgw" {
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the terraform template as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicated that Resource `urlPathMaps/value` referenced by resource `requestRoutingRules/default-Rule` was not found. You could check if you have referenced correct `url_path_map_name` in the block of `request_routing_rule`.

Here is the related terraform code for your reference

```
  frontend_port {
    name = "port_name2"
    port = 8080
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = "listener2"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = "port_name2"
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = "rule_2"
    rule_type                  = "PathBasedRouting"
    http_listener_name         = "listener2"
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
    url_path_map_name          = "urlmap"
  }

  url_path_map {
    name  = "urlmap"
    default_backend_address_pool_name = local.backend_address_pool_name
    default_backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name

    path_rule {
        name = "test"
        paths = ["/path1/"]
        backend_address_pool_name = local.backend_address_pool_name
        backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name

    }
  }
```